# Time difference of arrival - obtaining a hyperbola from equations, I have the starting values but I'm super confused with the equations.

Tags: education, hyperbolic-functions

I need help figuring out some calculations relating to Time Difference Of Arrival, I have two reference points (mics in the real wold), mic 1 and mic 2 are **1.01706** (feet) away from each other, this explanation explains the idea :

**" Once the signal is received at two reference points, the difference in arrival time can be used to calculate the difference in distances between the target and the two reference points. This difference can be calculated using the equation "**

**∆d = c ∗ (∆t)**

**c** is the **speed of sound** so 344 meters per second (since I'm using feet its **1125** ft per sec)

**∆t** is the **difference in arrival times** at each reference point.

I was 4ft ish away from the 2 reference points, made a sound and **difference in time** in seconds gave me **0.000044 seconds**.

I assume to satisfy the above equation I should be doing something like **0.000044 * 1125 = 0.0495**

is that part correct or should I somehow factor in the distance between the reference points **1.01706? e.g. 0.0495/1.01706**

Unfortunately there a second part which leads me completely lost...

**"In two dimensions, this leads to the following equation "**
[equation2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WwGF.png)

" where (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) are the known positions of the beacons. "

I have no idea how I would use my values with this? also how exactly would I do this... **"Using nonlinear regression this equation can be converted to the form of a hyperbola "**

Would it be possible to help me walk through these equations with my values (step by step if possible) ? Since I wish to do this with my other values myself thanks.

Comment: Do you see anything in your formula $\Delta d=c \Delta t$ that mentions the distance between microphones? As for how to use the second formula, $(x_1,y_2)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ are the coordinates of the two microphones. If you don’t have specific locations, pick a convenient coordinate system: setting them at $(\pm D/2,0)$, where $D$ is the distance between them, makes the resulting equations particularly simple to work with.

Comment: I don’t really see how nonlinear regression is relevant, though. Converting from the given equation that involves radicals into a more standard-looking conic equation is a matter of straightforward, though slightly messy, algebraic manipulation. Nonlinear regression comes in when you try to pinpoint the sound source by looking at the time differences for more than two microphones.